# switch from collect() to avoid java OOM when loading large table from Oracle to Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark

**BACKGROUND**:
I was trying to use load a huge table from Oracle to Hadoop and store the table in parquet format.
Since the table takes too long to be loaded, the Oracle section expired. So my new approach is to load the table in parallel with ranges of the index column in where clause.

So I used the following function to create an array of the list to be used in loops later but seems there will be OOM when the index column "indexUsed" has too many records. Any way to avoid using collect()?

```
distinctKeyValDf.sort("indexUsed").collect().map(_(0)).toList.sliding(recordNoInBatch, recordNoInBatch).toArray
```

this is what i am working on now, but seems the type is List[Nothing] instead of List[Any]

```
df.select(collect_list("indexUsed")).sort().first().getList(0).sliding(recordNoInBatch, recordNoInBatch).toArray
```

**Latest update:**
I was looking for a sliding function for dataframe but nothing pops up, so I used collect() for change the df into array. But that makes the java heap overloaded, so I switch to using collect_list in df, but seems the result returns array[nothing], which is not what i am looking for. I end up registering a temp table for the index column and create a for-loop + a do-while loop as a workaround for the sliding function.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Would you please review it with some input/output example ?

Comment: I still have a hard time understanding your problem properly, but I can assure you that calling `collect` in Spark is never the right solution unless you are debugging. Anyway, I would suggest that you just let Spark read the data, but you write that the table takes too long to be loaded? I assume you use `spark.read.jdbc`? What error is thrown?

Comment: I am using HiveContext.read.format("jdbc") and it took to long and Oracle section will expire(plus performance issue for other Oracle users). so i try to load a index column from oracle first, then split the index column in to pieces. The code I showed above is how i tried to split the index column into array[list(Any)].

Comment: I am actually trying to use mapPartition now. to see if that helps